# How to save all strings on listview using xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to save every time strings when button "Favorites" clicked and show on listview on another page.

From my first page I get the string from the button with this code:

```
void OnGetFavorites(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.Set("cityName", _cityEntry.Text);
        var tabbedPage = this.Parent.Parent as TabbedPage;
        tabbedPage.CurrentPage = tabbedPage.Children[2];
    }
```

From my second page I display the strings on the page with this code:

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        FavoriteCities();
    }

    private void FavoriteCities()
    {
        string cityName = Preferences.Get("cityName", "default_value");

        var listView = new ListView();

        listView.ItemsSource = new[] { cityName };

        // Using ItemTapped
        listView.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) => {
            await DisplayAlert("Tapped", e.Item + " row was tapped", "OK");
            Debug.WriteLine("Tapped: " + e.Item);
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
        };

        // If using ItemSelected
        //          listView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
        //              if (e.SelectedItem == null) return;
        //              Debug.WriteLine("Selected: " + e.SelectedItem);
        //              ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // de-select the row
        //          };

        Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);
        Content = listView;
    }

    void OnItemTapped(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

My ListView looks like:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Padding="0,30,0,0">

            <ListView x:Name="listView"
                      ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding .}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Now every time the old string is replaced with the new one. How can I arrange all the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a lot of different ways to approach this.  I'm going to give you a fairly simple one

first, you need a data structure to hold your data

```
ObservableCollection<string> CityData { get; set; }
```

then you need to update your XAML to bind to it

```
... ItemsSource="{Binding CityData}" />
```

then in the page constructor initialize `CityData` and set the BindingContext

```
CityData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
this.BindingContext = this;
```

**important** get rid of `FavoriteCities` there is nothing useful in there, and for some reason you are completely recreating the UI code that you already have in your XAML

then add a public method to your page to update the data

```
public void AddCity(string city)
{
   CityData.Add(city);
}
```

finally, in your other page

```
void OnGetFavorites(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // I really don't know what this is for
    Preferences.Set("cityName", _cityEntry.Text);

    var tabbedPage = this.Parent.Parent as TabbedPage;

    // important - cast to the correct type of Page2 - I don't know what that is
    var page = (MyPageClass) tabbedPage.Children[2];

    // add the new City
    page.AddCity(cityEntry.Text);

    // navigate
    tabbedPage.CurrentPage = page;
}
```

Comment: I receive error:  Specified cast is not valid. in Main.cs file on this line: UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");